# Pointcut for Inherited methods with super method calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, pointcut

I have the following classes

```
class A {
    public void someone() {
        helpMe();
    }
    private void helpMe() {
        // do something here
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void help() {
        super.someone();
    }
}
class C extends A {
    public void me() {
        super.someone();
    }
}
```

So I want to do something everytime `helpMe` method is called. `A.helpMe()` is never called explicitly. All of the method calls for `A.helpMe()` is through `A.someone()` which is further called through either `B.help()` or `C.me()`.

`helpMe` contains a common implementation that every other class needs.

pointcuts I have tried

```
execution(* A.helpMe(..)) // does not work
execution(* A+.helpMe(..)) // does not work
execution(* *.helpMe(..)) // does not work

execution(* A.*(..)) // does not work
execution(* B.someone(..)) // does not work
execution(* A+.*(..)) // forms a point cut for B.help() and C.me() only
execution(* *.*(..)) // forms a point cut for B.help() and C.me() only
execution(* B.*(..)) // forms a point cut for B.help() only
```

I read somewhere that `pointcuts` for `super` is not allowed. If thats the case, what are some valid work arounds?

I've tried getting `pointcut` with `annotations` but it does not work either.

Comment: Spring AOP is applied through proxies, internal method calls cannot be intercepted. For this you would need a full blown AOP solution like AspectJ with either load or compile time weaving.

Answer (score 0):

1 If in doubt, always fall back to to the fully hard-coded pointcut and work forward again:

```
execution(private void helpMe())
```

Are you sure you are [using AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) and not vanilla Spring AOP (which cannot advise a private method)?

FYI: https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-joinPoints.html

> the `call` join point does not capture super calls to non-static methods

... which is not not applicable to `execution`.